# How do I insert any Twitter user profile link while composing a tweet?

Tags: twitter, tweet

How do I insert any Twitter user profile link while composing a tweet?

It's almost like mentioning someone, but it shows a Twitter user's avatar & name just like in this tweet: https://twitter.com/DepressedDarth/status/924689808265482240?

Screenshot from a tweet:[image]

Comment: OK guys i actually found the answer, all we need to do is add /video/1 at the end of the video link it will embed the original tweet, so it can be tweeted as a new tweet and will show the original uploader badge(avatar) along with the video, many thanks to Terence Eden, his answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004060/how-to-insert-any-twitter-user-profile-link-while-composing-a-tweet/47014610#47014610

Comment: I have added your comment as an answer, you can accept the answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `/video/1` at the end of the video link it will embed the original tweet, so it can be tweeted as a new tweet and will show the original uploader badge(avatar) along with the video.

**[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47014610/4248931) is given by *Terence Eden* on Stack Overflow:**

> If you use the API to look at the status, using `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/924689808265482240.json` this is what you'll see
>
> ```
> "text": "This is what I do for fun now https:\/\/t.co\/VNEAbw4YRC",
> ```
>
> The user has sent a Tweet containing a link. Where does t.co/VNEAbw4YRC point to?
>
> https://twitter.com/DepressedDarth/status/879169042426318848/video/1
>
> So, here's what the user has done.
>
> 1. Post a video to Twitter - in this case, in June 2017.
> 2. Wait several months.
> 3. Copy the video URL of the Tweet - add `/video/1` to it.
> 4. Post a new Tweet and include the video URL of the old Tweet.
>
> Twitter will then render the Tweet with a link back to the original user who posted the video.  I think they do this to prevent people just linking to a different user's video and then claiming it for themselves.